# How to run windows store apps with proxifier

Tags: windows-10, proxy

I am in college and here we're allowed to access internet via the college proxy server only. I use a program named proxifier to tunnel all my connections(for the applications that do not support working through proxy) through the proxy. However It doesn't seem to work for windows store apps. Can anyone suggest how to tunnel store apps?

Comment: Does Proxifier give you an IP address and port number to connect (tunnel through) to ?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

For those who still searching for that, I found a solution
You can go to the "Profile" Tab -> "Advanced" -> "Services and Other Users ..."
then check "Window services and other system processes"

[image: Image of application of Proxifire]

Answer (score -2):

You don't need Proxifier, that is only used for tunneling normal applications (desktop programs) which don't have any inbuilt support for connecting through a proxy. If you have made an account in any VPN sites (e.g. PD Proxy, Your Freedom, Ultrasurf) then you need to first connect using their software, and then use the IP address and their port number (for example, 127.0.0.1 and 8080) as in [this link](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/setup-proxy-metro-application-windows-8).